# juju deploy timeout

Tags: juju

After I installed juju through the ppa and bootstrapped it, I haven't been able to deploy anything. Juju responds with this:

```
$ juju deploy mysql
2013-01-21 22:44:53,394 INFO Searching for charm cs:precise/mysql in charm store
2013-01-21 22:45:05,592 ERROR could not connect before timeout
```

It happens with every charm I've tried.

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.10. Fresh install too. 12.10 has been a real pain. Probably going to revert to 12.04 and wait it out until Raring if it's not going to work soon.

Answer (score 1):

You would receive that error if you were unable to connect to the Juju charm store at http://jujucharms.com/.  So, you might be blocked by a firewall that is preventing you from connecting to the charm store and so it is timing out, when it tries to download the mysql charm.

You could check that you can connect to the charm store by trying the command:

```
wget http://jujucharms.com/
```

It should save an index.html file if you can connect. If it times out you have a problem accessing the charm store and you would have to manually copy the charms locally and then use a command like:

```
juju deploy --repository /path/to/charm-repo local:mysql
```

If you want to download a copy of all the charms from the charm store for copying to your system then install the package charm-tools and use the following commands:

```
cd dir/where/you/will/store/this
mkdir -p charm-repo/precise
charm getall charm-repo/precise
```

If you have no luck and want to debug juju further use the -v flag for verbose output:

```
juju -v deploy mysql
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the exact same error and after running with '-v' it became clear the problem was with the zookeeper server, which indeed wasn't running:

2013-02-28 18:19:02,019:18960(0x7f172f531700):ZOO_INFO@zookeeper_init@727: Initiating client connection, host=10.0.3.1:48948 sessionTimeout=10000 watcher=0x7f172eda0700 sessionId=0 sessionPasswd= context=0x1ec9150 flags=0

I couldn't find out why it wasn't running, but the problem went away after I changed my data-dir in environments.yaml and ran 'juju bootstrap' again.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @Pilot6 this is an attempt to answer the question, with at least a partial answer.

Comment: @Seth I read it three times and after some consideration decided that it was rather a comment.

Answer (score 0):

I got same error, in MAAS 1.5

The problem was I set my MAAS server time as my local time PST, After I changed it to UTC , it worked.

After full installation of my services I changed time zone to my local time again.